# How to execute multiple constructor, when creating single object

Tags: java, constructor

I want to execute multiple constructor, while creating a single object. For example, I have a class definition like this-

```
public class Prg
{
    public Prg()
    {
        System.out.println("In default constructor");
    }
    public Prg(int a)
    {
        System.out.println("In single parameter constructor");
    }
    public Prg(int b, int c)
    {
        System.out.println("In multiple parameter constructor");
    }
}
```

And I am trying to achieve it by the following code -

```
public class Prg
{
    public Prg()
    {
        System.out.println("In default constructor");
    }
    public Prg(int a)
    {
        Prg();
        System.out.println("In single parameter constructor");
    }
    public Prg(int b, int c)
    {
        Prg(b);
        System.out.println("In multiple parameter constructor");
    }
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        Prg obj = new Prg(10, 20);
    }
}
```

But in this case it is generating errors like -

```
Prg.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
            Prg();
            ^
  symbol:   method Prg()
  location: class Prg
Prg.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
            Prg(b);
            ^
  symbol:   method Prg(int)
  location: class Prg
2 errors
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `this()` instead of `Prg()` in your constructors

Comment: Oh, thanks. I was searching for keywords like super, to point the same class. But I didn't tried this. Now it's working.

Answer (score 6):

Use `this` instead of `Prg`

```
    public Prg()
    {
        System.out.println("In default constructor");
    }
    public Prg(int a)
    {
        this();
        System.out.println("In single parameter constructor");
    }
    public Prg(int b, int c)
    {
        this(b);
        System.out.println("In multiple parameter constructor");
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

use `this` keyword.Full running code is as follows

```
public class Prg
{
    public Prg()
    {
        System.out.println("In default constructor");
    }
    public Prg(int a)
    {
        this();
        System.out.println("In single parameter constructor");
    }
    public Prg(int b, int c)
    {
        //Prg obj = new Prg(10, 20);

this(b);        System.out.println("In multiple parameter constructor");
    }
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        Prg obj = new Prg(10, 20);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `this` statement.

e.g.

```
public Prg(int b, int c)
{
    this(b);
    System.out.println("In multiple parameter constructor");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When calling other constructors Use `this()` instead of `Prg()`