# Using multiple constructors with one object in Java

Tags: java

I have two constructors for Student and am trying to use both of them with one object.  But I should be doing it wrong because my output is not what I expect it to be.

Output:
School: null
Grade Level: 0
Intended Major: null

Student's ID number is: 154324
Student's name: Sam Bay
Student's GPA: 3.56

Code for class definition:

```
public class Student
{
   private int id, gradeLevel;
   private String name, school, major;
   private double gpa;


   //constructor to initialize the instance variables of student object
   public Student(int id, String name, double gpa)
   {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.gpa = gpa;
   }

   public Student(int gradeLevel, String school, String major)
   {
      this.gradeLevel = gradeLevel;
      this.school = school;
      this.major = major;
   }    

   //toString() to display the attributions of the student object
   public String toString()
   {
      return "School: " + school +
             "\nGrade Level: " + gradeLevel +
             "\nIntended Major: " + major + "\n" +
             "\nStudent's ID number is: " + id +
             "\nStudent's name: " + name +
             "\nStudent's GPA: " + gpa;
   }

}//end class
```

code for main:

```
public class StudentDrive

    {
       public static void main(String [] args)
       {
      //creating student objects
      Student sam = new Student(12, "Alpha High School", "Biology");
      sam = new Student(154324, "Sam Bay", 3.56);

      System.out.println(sam);

   }
}
```

It seems like I've initialized the first part but I get null and 0??!!!

Comment: The info you enter in the first object creation is lost when you create a completely new second object. My question is why would you want to do it like this?

Comment: You're only ever going to initialize half of the variables you want, anyway.  There's a slightly better approach to do this, but it depends on which way you want to go; are you comfortable with one giant constructor, or would you be more open to a builder?

Comment: See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999635/how-to-execute-multiple-constructor-when-creating-single-object) for the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use two constructors simultaneously on a single object.

In your code:

`Student sam = new Student(12, "Alpha High School", "Biology");`

creates a new `Student` object and assigns its *reference* to the variable `sam`.

On your next line:

`sam = new Student(154324, "Sam Bay", 3.56);`

This creates **another** `Student` object, separate from the first, and reassigns `sam` to refer to it instead. In the process, you end up orphaning the original `Student` and leave it open to garbage collection.

What you really want to do is either pass *all* data required for by a `Student` through a single constructor, **or** provide getters/setters (e.g. `setGradeLevel(int level)`) and a layer of exceptions that prevent methods from accessing a `Student` object until all fields are filled. The first option is generally more sound.

For example, a complete constructor would look something like this (formatted for readability):

```
public Student(int id, int gradeLevel, String name, 
               String school, String major, double gpa)
{
    // fill your fields in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read through the docs for a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) again ;)

With `Student sam = new Student(12, "Oakton High School", "Biology");`
you are creating a Student-object with the given parameters and storing it in the variable sam.

When you call `sam = new Student(154324, "Sam Bay", 3.56);` you are again creating a **new** Student-object and storing it in sam. You are not modifying the first object but rather discarding it and creating a new one.

You should try adding a method to your Student object like:

```
public void setAdditionalValues(int id, String name, double gpa){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.gpa = gpa;
}
```

Hope this is helpful :)

EDIT: as mentioned earlier you could also use one constructor that takes all the arguments or implement setters for each attribute of the Student-object like this:

```
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
```